# Laptop keeps disconnecting from WiFi (Netgear WNR614 N300)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireshark, arp

So my laptop(Ubuntu 20.04) keeps DC'ing from my WiFi. But my phone is properly connected to it and so is my amazon fire stick.

I ran **wireshark** to check the problem and there seemed to be an **ARP** issue.

Like, the ISP is asking the IP of router to my Laptop but there ain't any answer from my router.

How can I solve this problem?
I will attach the log of the network traffic.

[My network Traffic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1iyN.png)

Answer (score -1):

try lowering wireless to 54Mbps instead of 300Mbps
this router comes with weird hardware config
downlink is greater than uplink where you connect your wan/lan through fastethernet with only 100Mbps ports while wireless is up to 300/145/54 Mbps

Answer (score -2):

Your Wifi router is probably at the end of its life and/or you are too far away or you have metal between your router and laptop. Get a new wifi router cause the antennaes do expire after some years and create mini-disconnects. Your Wifi router is also released in 2017.

These mini-disconnects don't matter when watching YouTube on your phone or watching Amazon shows on your firestick since the video is streaming/downloading **ahead** by a few minutes. Those few minutes you could have already been disconnected, but your devices have reconnected quickly, within 5 seconds.

Your computer will show disconnects easily if your are working a program that needs a constant **live** internet connection (eg. online games) and the smallest hiccup will create a big wifi disconnect error.

Either that or your wifi card in your laptop is needing to be replaced. Many Lenovo laptops are infamous for crappy wifi cards that have limited range/speed/disconnects.

You can buy a cheap $10-20 USD wifi adaptor for usb from Amazon and test it out in your laptop to see if it is the laptop wifi card or your router antennae.

Comment: Yeah, i thought it might be a router issue as well. Did you check the traffic log? Does that point to the router or the laptop?